# Update all tables using trigger

Tags: triggers, sql-update

My customer table is (customer_id, customerName). Almost all the tables have customerName column. I need to make a trigger that will update all the customerNames' in Database when the customerName in customer table is updated or changed.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to normalise your database, so that other tables do not hold a customer name, rather they hold a reference to the customer_id.  This way customer details only need to be updated in the customer table.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But I need to do it this way, as it is an assignment :(